# System.getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR") is returning null value in intelliJ IDEA ultimate edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4, junit5

Java version:

```
java 11.0.14 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263
```

IntelliJ IDEA ultimate version: `2021.3.2`

**Default shell set to bash**

when running from IntelliJ the junit test class file, test cases are failing because it is not able to fetch one env variable.
`System.getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR")` is returning `null` value.

But when I am running from terminal using `mvn test -Dtest="TestFile"` test cases are getting passed because `System.getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR")` is returning a proper value.

Comment: How do you run IDE?

Comment: You need to add environment variable to your run configuration. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/add-environment-variables-and-program-arguments.html#add-environment-variables

Comment: If it returns null, the variable is not set.  Check the javadoc